# the best way to include js file in zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I want to include external js file in my php script. I am following zend framework.Right now I am adding js file in controller's init function like this.

```
public function init() {
    $this->doUserAuthorisation();
    parent::init();
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/js/front_cal/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');  
    $this->view->headLink()->setStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl().'/styles/front_cal/calendar.css');
}
```

problem what i am facing is, js file doesnot include.Is this the right way to include js file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript (and images, CSS, flash movies, etc) belong to the view layer so configure them there.

For globally included files, add them to your layout, eg

```
<!-- layout.phtml -->
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile(
        $this->baseUrl('path/to/file.js')) ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet(
        $this->baseUrl('path/to/file.css')) ?>

<!-- snip -->

    <?php echo $this->inlineScript()->prependFile(
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js') ?>
</body>
```

Your view scripts can then add assets to the helpers which are echoed out in the layout. As the layout uses the `prepend*()` methods, the global files will be displayed first, eg

```
<?php // views/scripts/index/index.phtml
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl('path/to/script.js'));
```

Comment: hey do you know the default location of layout.pthml? I cant find it on my server.

Comment: @Xitcod, `Application\view\layout\layout.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

In above solution the 'path/to/file.js' script will be included in the header twice. There is no need for `echo` before calling `prependFile`. Such behaviour can lead to duplicating javascript controls.

`<!-- layout.phtml -->
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile(
        $this->baseUrl('path/to/file.js'))  // this will echo out the whole prependFile queue`

Comment: Do you mean my answer above? Not sure what you mean about it being included twice. Your answer is identical to the same part of mine