# jquery plugin in zend framework

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, jquery-plugins

I recently started working on a website with zend framework.
I am trying to include simple jquery plugins but i have no idea what is the proper way to include them.

I have found the main index.phtml sites but none of them have a  element nor the php code to include the javascript as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100197/the-best-way-to-include-js-file-in-zend-framework).
I also dont have a layout.phtml file on my server.

So where are all the javascript files added? I been looking for them everywhere but cant find them.
Where should i link my own jquery plugins and javascript files.

Any help on this would be appreciated I am new to zend framework.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help unless you can show what you actually have. I'd suggest creating a layout and adding the code as per the question you linked. That is, after all, the correct way.

Comment: So then you would ouput them in whatever phtml files render the head/body tags as appropriate. But it would definitely be better to use the Layout component and consolidate stuff there.

Comment: Alright i will create a layout file and include my js files there. where in the directory tree should the layout file be located? I will edit my question today to include some additional details so maybe i can find out where the current js files are linked. Like i said im new to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Default location for layout files is in `application/layouts` but you can check in `application/configs/application.ini` for `resources.layout.layoutPath` to check where they are. There is a chance that your project does not use layouts (they are not required part of zend).

You can try looking for `<HTML>` or `<HEAD>` tags or by js file names in all project files to find where they are added.

Proper way of adding them is by using helper `headScript()`(usually for scripts in header of page) or/and `inlineScript()`(this is confusing name because usually used at bottom of page) like this:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile('/js/jQuery.js'); //this add to list of files
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile('/js/main.js');
```

Then add in layout:

```
echo $this->headScript() //this will actually print files from list
echo $this->inlineScript()
```

Comment: thanks your answer helped me find where the scripts are most likely added. Im my layouts/modules/default.phtml there is a php code: `<?php echo $this->headLink(); ?> <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>` I just dont know where to find the code for `headLink()` as default.phtml is in the views folder and doesnt contain any function definitions. I have no idea where to look for headScript function.

Comment: Easiest way is to use IDE which can search all files in project for `headScript()` :)